# Are huge node_modules and bower_components directories necessary on production?

Tags: deployment, web-deployment

I'm deploying something into a remote server from my local development environment (`vagrant` / `homestead`). In my project I have huge directories for both `node_modules` and `bower_components`. I want to use `rsync` to deploy project on a remote server but I think it's OK to skip mentioned giants. Why?

By writing this question I would like to confirm 2 things:

1) Since I triggered gulp tasks on my local, is it all right **NOT TO COPY** those 2 vendor directories if my assets are already copied, minified and versioned using Laravel Elixir? Obviously compiled styles and scripts will be synced.

*(that's non-Laravel project) but I use Elixir in my `gulpfile.js` for it's simplicity*

2) Or should deployment process include installing assets (like `npm install`) on remote server and then running all tasks? I think it's wrong in that case. What if for example I won't be able to install and run `npm` on remote?

So in a nutshell. Can I consider `node_modules` and `bower_components` as essential resources only during development and redundant once deployed?

Answer (score 0):

Yes you are right in that once the javascript app has been transpiled, all dependencies(node_modules, bower_componenets, etc) would have been removed by your gulp script and packaged into a single bundle.